# Android height of elements calculation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout which consists of a scrollview.
Inside the scrollview there is a linear layout, which inside has a few more layouts.
The problem is the scroll gets too long, because of the height of it's first child.

I measured (getMeasuredHeight) the height and I dont understand why the first child is so long.

The results of the heights are:

child: 800

headerlayout: 100

button_view: 143

button_view_footer: 150

showit: 50 (Its a button directly withinthe child) inside

This is the XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/firstchild"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/page4biz">
 <TextView 
android:id="@+id/tags"
android:layout_width="310dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:visibility="gone"
/>
 <RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:id="@+id/headerlayout"
  >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
 <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/urlTitle"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/format"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/lastdate"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/format"
    android:textColor="#000000"
/>
   </RelativeLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/button_view"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center">
              <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:background="@drawable/content"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:maxLines = "5"
                android:scrollbars = "vertical"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
              <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/Title"
                android:layout_width="310dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />
              <Button android:background="@drawable/content"
                      android:layout_width="300dp"
                      android:layout_height="50dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:textSize="14sp"
                      android:visibility="gone"/>

              <Button android:background="@drawable/content"
                      android:layout_width="300dp"
                      android:layout_height="50dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:textSize="14sp"
                      android:visibility="gone"/>

              <Button android:background="@drawable/content"
                      android:layout_width="300dp"
                      android:layout_height="50dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:textSize="14sp"
                      android:visibility="gone"/>

              <Button android:background="@drawable/content"
                      android:layout_width="300dp"
                      android:layout_height="50dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:textSize="14sp"
                      android:visibility="gone"/>

                <Button android:background="@drawable/content"
                      android:layout_width="300dp"
                      android:layout_height="50dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:textSize="14sp"
                      android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/button_view_footer"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center">

      <Button android:background="@drawable/content"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

      <Button android:background="@drawable/content"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

      <Button android:background="@drawable/content"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

      <Button android:background="@drawable/content"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

      <Button android:id="@+id/s_button"
              android:layout_width="0dip"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:drawableLeft="@drawable/shopper_icon"
              android:drawablePadding="4dip"
              android:text="@string/button_google_shopper"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>
      <Button 
              android:background="@drawable/content"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:id="@+id/showit"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
      />
          </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollView>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried placing another scrollview inside the specific layout you want?

Comment: @Kurty No, I didn't. How would it change the problem? the first linear layout will still be 800, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using match_parent for the height on your ScrollView, and wrap_content for the height on your LinearLayout (firstChild).

And, for good measure, add `android:fillViewport="true"` to your ScrollView.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the problem? What does "the scroll gets too long" mean exactly?

Comment: Because the "first child" height is 800 (and this actually what I'm tryign to understand), there is a lot more scrolling then needed.

Comment: Well, how tall do you expect it to be? If your screen is WVGA and is in portrait mode, then it's going to be 800 units tall. If the content is not tall enough to fill that, there should be no scrolling. If the content is taller than that, there will be scrolling. Is the background on the first child 800px tall?

Comment: No, the device I am testing on now is 320X480 (Samsung Galaxy Ace).

Comment: You got me thinking, and I think maybe it's the image background size that causes the problem...I will check it.

Comment: It was the background image...3 hours of my life lost :)
Thanks a lot for your help!